# Why, after the correct operation of the spring mvc method, ajax shows a message from the error?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I note once again, there are no errors in the method, I do not understand why only ajax displays an error message.
I assume that the problem is in the return value of the method, but I do not quite understand what to do with it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form.changeRoleForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data=  {
            "id": $(this).children("input.id").val(),
            "role" : $(this).children("select.role").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'changerole',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),


            success: function() {
                alert("Role "+ data.role+" of user by id "+data.id+"  was successfully installed!");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Something went wrong. Role not updated");
                $(this).css('color', 'green');
                location.reload();
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Method from controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "changerole")
        public String changeRole(@RequestBody String jsonData) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> map;
        map = mapper.readValue(jsonData, HashMap.class);
        String role = map.get("role");
        String id = map.get("id");
        User user= userDAO.findById(Integer.valueOf(id));
        user.setRole(role);
        userDAO.update(user);
        return "success";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happenning because your controller is returning normal text string instead of a valid `JSON` response.

Ensure that controller returns valid JSON.

Update your method like below to return valid JSON.

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "changerole")
@ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<String> changeRole(@RequestBody String jsonData) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> map;
        map = mapper.readValue(jsonData, HashMap.class);
        String role = map.get("role");
        String id = map.get("id");
        User user= userDAO.findById(Integer.valueOf(id));
        user.setRole(role);
        userDAO.update(user);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"msg\":\"success\"}", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

and then in AJAX

```
success: function(response) {
    alert("msg "+ response.msg+");
   if(response.msg === 'success'){
      //code on success
   }
}
```

Comment: what should be headers in return?

Comment: updated answer..HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");..check once and let me know if any issue.

Comment: I correctly understand that now using the line: if (response.msg === 'success')
I do not need ajax to do an error handler?

Comment: still errors will be returned in the error part only in case of exception...otherwise you can return failure also from the controller so that one more condition for failure you can put inside success.